# HIde button inside controllerScope columns definition

Tags: angularjs

I have a button which will only be available for users of type "Administrator". So I verify the group of permissions of the user logged in the system and determine if I show/hdie the button.

So I try, ng-if / ng-show /ng-hide and nothing worked... I'm logged as a Monitor and the button shold not be available.

My code:

```
app.controller('OrganizationsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', 'HelperService', 'AuthService', '$state', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $modal, HelperService, AuthService, $state, $http) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;

        controllerScope.organizationsData = {};
        controllerScope.organizationsData.ajax = {url:'/api/organizations/', dataSrc:''};
        controllerScope.organizationsData.ajax.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", AuthService.authToken());
        }

        controllerScope.permissionGroup=$rootScope.permissions.group_name;

        controllerScope.organizationsData.columns = [
            {"data":null,"render":function(data) {
                return '<a href="/#/organization/'+data.id+'">'+data.data.name+'</a>';
            }},
            {"data":"domain","defaultContent":""},
            {"data":null, "orderable":false, "render":function(data){
                return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;" ng-if="controllerScope.permissionGroup.indexOf(\'Administrator\')!==-1" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().openOrganizationPermissionsSettings(\''+data.id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>'
                +'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px; " onclick=\'angular.element(this).scope().openNewOrganizationModal('+JSON.stringify(data)+')\'><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'
                +'<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().deleteOrganization(\''+data.id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
            }}];


        controllerScope.deleteOrganization = function (organizationId) {
            HelperService.deleteItem(organizationId, 'organization', '/api/organizations/');
        };
```

So the most important lines are:

`controllerScope.permissionGroup=$rootScope.permissions.group_name` which returns "Monitor"

and

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"
       data-if="controllerScope.permissionGroup.indexOf(\'Administrator\')!==-1" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().openOrganizationPermissionsSettings(\''+data.id+'\')">
    <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>'
```

where I create the button and manage its visibility.

right now the button is always available as the image above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use `data-ng-hide` directive so you cannot just append DOM element without to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it. Angular has no idea about your changes and digest cycle doesn't listen on your new created `data-ng-hide`

---

As a side note: don't use `onclick`, use `ng-click`

---

Some basic example:

```
   var el = angular.element(
            '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="foo()" ng-show="someCondition"></button>'
            );

    el = $compile(el)($scope);
    var warapper = document.querySelector('#warapper');
    angular.element(warapper).append(el);
```

Comment: Wanst enough just to use ng-if? How to use $compile?

Comment: @AndréBastos not at all, all angular directives should be compiled

Comment: For me was simple to use ng-if.. how to do this with ng-if? For example.. if i use ng-.click the onclick event dont popup instead with onclick it work...

Comment: @AndréBastos because `onclick` is not related to angular. `ng-if` directive will not work too in your case

Comment: Ok but now how I have this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/0EpoH9dWJuYczYGhiFrL?p=catalogue Ca n you help me please?

Comment: The problem is with data.id in the var el... I need that and I just have that info after...

Comment: What can I do? @Maxim